# How to define parameters in Spring RequestBody as not null?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to be able to define certain variables as not null in **Spring**'s `@RequestBody`. That way Spring's controller will reject any requests whose body doesn't have certain variables that I define as critical. I've tried the code below however it doesn't work:

The controller:

```
@PutMapping("/")
ResponseEntity updateOptions(
   @RequestBody RequestDto requestDto
);
```

The `RequestDto`, *I want the first parameter to always be filled*:

```
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

public class RequestDto {
   @NotNull
   String id;

   String message;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add the `@Valid` annotation.

```
@PutMapping("/")
ResponseEntity updateOptions(
   @Valid @RequestBody RequestDto requestDto
);
```

If you are using `Spring Boot 2.3` and higher, we also need to add the "spring-boot-starter-validation" dependency:

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId> 
</dependency>
```

For more detailed examples you can review the article "[Validation in Spring Boot](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-bean-validation)".